# Selenium Table and div overlapping

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, automation

Working on scraping Web page which has very complex table and div.
On click of a button new page appears with above table.

Scraping code is working fine i am able to get fields that i want but
sometimes after that button click table appears with some fields/rows overlapped and xpath doesn't match
and correct values are not extracted with selenium script. This thing doesn't happen manually.

If overlapping happens in between script and if i manually zoom down 10% table forms properly.

I dont know why the overlapping is happening with script and not manually please needs suggestions.

Comment: Selenium use temporary browser profile with different zoom or device pixel ratio or or ... Selenium tries to click on first pixel of webelement and bcs those differences sometimes it simply miss. There are two approaches to fix this. 1. setup browser properties (like ChromeOptions etc.) before launching browser. 2. use Action and moveToElement(element) before click.

Comment: Starting Chrome with parameter --window-size=1920x1080 helped me to avoid those missclicks.